# Lock/Protect document directory of ios app

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, ios6

I want to make document folder of my IOS app that is not accessible to user while he use software like iexplorer. How can i fix this issue. Document folder contains pdf,video etc. I want to make document folder not accessible to user.

Answer (score 5):

You can't. If you want to protect your data, encrypt it